# How can I put a fixed shadow on the bottom item of a list?

Tags: html, css

I have a file picker. When I select some file like this,

[image]

there is a shadow on the bottom.

When I add more files like this,

[image]

the shadow must be still at the bottom.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please read this arthttps://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and also attach your code.

Comment: Produce some code yourself, to be corrected! Also, your problem still NOT clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you started. It's not really a shadow, but linear-gradient background will provide the effect you are looking for though you will have to tweak the values to get it exactly how you want.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  flex: 1;
}

.container img {
  margin: 0 0 12px 0;
}

.overlay {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 39%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQMHH.jpg" height="200" />
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQMHH.jpg" height="200" />
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQMHH.jpg" height="200" />
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQMHH.jpg" height="200" />
  <div class="overlay"> </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use from a div for shadow with **position: relative**, as the last div:

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 1px white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  background-image: url(https://s4.uupload.ir/files/گیتار-14_1x2o.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.shadow {
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7));
  position: relative;
  top: -140px;/*equal to height & padding from divs*/
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div class="shadow"></div>
</body>
```